# Joining/Querying Tables by a Substring

Tags: sql, sql-server

Currently I have a query which is partly based on a join on two tables according to two number columns within them.

Say one table has a number like 123456789999 (NUM1)

And the other table has a number ranging from 1 - 9999 (NUM2)

I want to pull out the records which have 'NUM2' within the 5th - 8th digits of 'NUM1'

Currently I am doing something like this,

```
FROM Table1 AS T INNER JOIN Table2 AS S 
ON SUBSTRING(T.num1, 5, 4) = S.num2
```

I know it should be retrieving approx 100 records, but I only get 8. I believe it to be because of the small ranges within number two. Where have I gone wrong? OR how could my code be made more robust/effective?

Comment: Are the column data types strings, e.g. `VARCHAR`, or numeric, e.g. `BIGINT`?

Comment: NUM1 is a varchar, NUM2 is an int.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `CAST` like this:

```
FROM Table1 AS T INNER JOIN Table2 AS S 
ON CAST(SUBSTRING(T.num1, 5, 4) AS INT) = S.num2
```

[SEE THIS FIDDLE](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/1f815/1)

For more info see [SQL SERVER – Convert Text to Numbers (Integer) – CAST and CONVERT](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/07/07/sql-server-convert-text-to-numbers-integer-cast-and-convert/)

Comment: Thanks for the idea, within your fiddle you had table2 with values 9999, 9998, 9997, 9996, however when they are changed to smaller numbers, 9, 99, 999 for example, they aren't found by the query.

Comment: Apologies, you are right, I tested it incorrectly. Many thanks!

Comment: @William231 Then you need to put num1 value like this `123400999997` or `123400099997`.
So you will also get the value with 9,99 etc. [See this fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a0d86/1)

Answer (score 1):

try this:

Since the datatype of NUM2 is int, 0001 will be considered as just 1

so try this:

```
 FROM Table1 AS T INNER JOIN Table2 AS S 
ON cast(SUBSTRING(T.num1, 5, 4) as int) = S.num2
```